# Get All Strings Between Two Different Tags

Tags: python, regex, scrape, beautifulsoup

I am trying to put together a chat log of conversations i've had with people. I want to be able to break it out by name, time, and text.  Because the conversations I'm pulling aren't in a nice and neat CSV file, I need to scrape from the source code. I get the following code like below. Is there any way to pull all the strings between the `<div class='message'>` and `</p>` so I can put together each individual chat message with the respective sender and time sent? Thanks!

```
<div class="message"><div class="message_header"><span class="user">First Lastname</span><span class="meta">Tuesday, January 1, 2000 at 5:00pm EST</span></div></div><p>text here</p>
```

Comment: Use beautifulsoup to operate on the structured document rather than try to write a regex: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: What do you want to pull out of it? The message header, the time and the name?

Comment: I want to pull class="user", class="meta", and anything between <p> and </p>. Possible there is no text between paragraph tags....

Comment: Are each of the messages on a separate line?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2823755

Comment: I think using a regex like `(?=((<p)|(class=\"(user|meta)))).*?>([^<]+)` can helps ;).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using regular expressions. Here is what i came up with. Note Regex is tested, but the python code is not complete. However you should be able to figure out what i'm doing. If you need more explanation on the regex or way to implement it, let me know. I'll adjust my answer.

```
import re

#Put this in a loop to get all files   
    line = #get line from file
    m = re.match(r"<div class=\"message\">.*<span class=\"user\">(.*)<\/span><span class=\"meta\">(.*)<\/span>.*<p>(.*)<\/p>", line)
    name = m.group(1)       # The name
    time = m.group(2)       # Time
    message = m.group(3)    # Message
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure it out with BeautifulSoup 4. Fortunately the length of user, time, and messages was the same. I broke out each user, time, and message into their own lists. Then used a for loop to go through each list and match [i] of each user, time, and message together into one list, then append to another list. Now porting over to a CSV should be a cake walk.

```
    texts = []
    times = []
    users = []

    for text in soup.find_all('p'):
        text = text.string
        texts.append(text)
    for time in soup.find_all('span', class_='meta'):
        time = time.string
        times.append(time)
    for user in soup.find_all('span', class_='user'):
        user = user.string
        users.append(user)
conversations = []

for i in range(0,len(users)):
    x = users[i]
    y = times[i]
    z = texts[i]
    chat = [x , y, z]
    conversations.append(chat)
print(conversations)
```